# Jenkins Plugin with proxy

Tags: proxy, jenkins-plugins

I am have a Jenkins CI with the following configuration:

- Tomcat on Open SUSE [openSUSE 13.1 (x86_64)] [Jenkins v1.532.3]
- Java version "1.7.0_51" [OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.4) (suse-24.13.5-x86_64)].

I am positive that I have my proxy configured correctly. But when I try to download a plugin or update a plugin on Jenkins. I get this error

```
    Git Client Plugin   
     Failure -
    hudson.util.IOException2: Failed to download from http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/git-client/1.8.1/git-client.hpi
        at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:794)
        .
        .
Caused by: java.net.ProtocolException: Server redirected too many  times (20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        .
        .
        .
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:764)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.net.ProtocolException: Server redirected too many  times (20)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1636)
```

But I am able to do a Curl or a wget to the actual URL/URI to download the plugin

Thanks for your help and feedback

Comment: Having a similar issue, have you had any luck with this?

Comment: Possibly related Jenkins issue : https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-21633

Answer (score 0):

I don't think, that this is still relevant, but may be could help to someone else..

I had a similar issue after I changed my password. I checked different proxies and each time had the same issue. Now that I have changed the password again to have more standard symbols, the issues is immediately gone.

So it seems, that sometimes there can be just some problem with some special characters in the password.

Hope that could help someone.

Best Regards,
Viacheslav